# Setting user ip using Mixpanel PHP library

Tags: php, ip, mixpanel

I'm setting user details using Mixpanel PHP library ($mixpanel->people->set). It works fine, email, registration date etc. are set correctly.

However the location (Country, City, Tomezone) attributes are all wrong. I believe this could be solved by setting the user IP somehow (since we're seding a "hit" from backend and our server IP might be used by default). The problem is Mixpanel API reference doesn't mention this even once.

How can this be achieved? How can I set the IP address for my Mixpanel users?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found an answer myself.

Apparently the reference does mention it.

> Set properties on a user record.
>
> set(string | int $distinct_id, array $props, string | null $ip)  If
>   the profile does not exist, it creates it with these properties. If it
>   does exist, it sets the properties to these values, overwriting
>   existing values.
>
> Parameters
>
> $distinct_id stringint the distinct_id or alias of a user
>
> $props array associative array of properties to set on the profile
>
> $ip stringnull the ip address of the client (used for geo-location)

So the user IP is the third parameter of the set method.

The quote if from [here](http://mixpanel.github.io/mixpanel-php/classes/Producers_MixpanelPeople.html#method_set)